# Some features have curves and were ignored using Split features tool of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, features, splitting, true-curves

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have a river buffer (polygon) that I want to split using Split features. The cutting feature is municipality borders. When I use the tool, it says:

> Some features have curves and were ignored.

What does that mean?

I used this tool earlier today to split several polygons in a layer, so I don't see why this should be any different.

Comment: To be clear: no polygons seem to have been split.

Comment: Its not clear if the warning is related to your buffers or  your municipal polygons? Either way some of the polygons will be constructed with Bezier curves. These are obvious as they are smooth mathematically calculated curving edges and won't have that segmented look as a line is constructed from the vertices.

Comment: They must be related to the buffers, since I managed to split other polygons with the municipal polygons earlier in the day. I am not sure what your point is about the Bézier curves. The buffer is created from a line though.

Comment: Without seeing your data can't really comment but a line or polygon can be constructed by a series of vertices clicked and/or additionally Bezier curves.